# GTK and INotify don't work together

Tags: haskell

Using GHC, on Ubuntu 13.10, iNotify works-

```
import Control.Concurrent
import System.INotify

main = do
    n <- initINotify
    addWatch n [Modify] "/home/fred/" $ \event -> do
        putStrLn $ "file changed: " ++ show event
    threadDelay 10000000
```

and GTK2HS works-

```
import Graphics.UI.Gtk

main = do
    initGUI
    {-Add your widgets here....  or don't, the bug appears either way.-}
    mainGUI
```

But if I put the two together, inotify never triggers.  (it compiles and runs though....)

```
main = do
    n <- initINotify
    addWatch n [Modify] "/home/fred/" $ \event -> do
        putStrLn $ "file changed: " ++ show event
    initGUI
    mainGUI
```

I've tried putting the inotify and GTK stuff in separate threads, it made no difference.  I suspect something like a signal collision between the libs....

Oh, and in case it matters, I am trying to build a small tool that runs in the background, watches for file changes, and displays some info in the application indicator when this happens.

---

Note-

To trigger iNotify, just create or modify a file in the directory given in addWatch....

```
echo "abcd" > /home/fred/aFile
```

`touch` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I have a pretty good guess what's going wrong here (the main loop is being run by C and never re-enters Haskell land, so Haskell threads don't get a chance to run), but I can't test. Your first program never produces output for me (even if I change "/home/fred" appropriately). Can you add one or two sentences describing how to run the first program?

Comment: @DanielWagner- Sorry, I made a *small* mistake, and just fixed it....  Add a "/" at the end of the filename "/home/<username>/" in addWatch to watch the contents in the directory, then any filechanges in this directory will trigger the code (ie- `echo "abcd" > /home/fred/aFile` should do the trick, `touch` doesn't seem to work though)....  I actually did test my code before posting, but changed the filename at the last moment :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile (actually, technically, link) with `-threaded`. This way the inotify thread will be evacuated from the `main` execution context before the `mainGUI` loop goes into C-land and stops cooperatively switching to the GHC runtime. More details on multi-threading and gtk are available at [this post](http://dmwit.com/gtk2hs) I wrote a while ago.